# jquery window resize div height

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I am trying to resize a div's height when the page change's size.  In my current state it works great on page load.  But when I go to change the browser size it does not work.  If I throw an alert in the script it fires every time the page resizes but won't change the css of the div.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">dddA box full of teddddddddddxt and sometdddhing elsdedd andd else adnd dsomddething besiddeds dddddd dddddd ddd ddd d ddddeddxdtdd andddddd somdddddething else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">A box full of texdt and something else and else and something besiclasss text and something else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">A box full of tdext and something else and else and something besiclasss text and something else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">A box full of tedxt and something else and else and something besides text and something else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">A box full of text and something else and else and something besides text and something else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="page" style="margin-top:15px;height:auto;background-color:grey;padding-top:15px;">
            <div id="topbox" style="width:170px;height:100px;margin:15px;background-color:white;"></div>
            <div class="text">A box full of text and something else and else and something besides text and something else.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery script:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
         var bodyheight = $('.text').height();
         $(".text").height(bodyheight);
     });

      $(window).resize(function() {
         function checkWidth(){
         var bodyheight = $('.text').height();
         $(".text").height(bodyheight);     
      }
       checkWidth();
       $(window).resize();
    });

</script>
```

Is this possible to do and if so how much work on browser is it to use something like this?  Thanks for your help.

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/g9c41hfv/

Second Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/d1a0rv8r/  you have to resize screen to start it

Comment: btw,you could directly put the $(window).resize code,why put it inside a function?

Comment: yes you are correct but I am trying to debug this and I know calling it this way should make it do what I want but maybe not cause its not working...

Comment: You're setting the height to what it already is.  You're reading the height, and saving it in a var (bodyheight), and then setting the height of the same element (.text) to it's own height.

Comment: Use media queries css

Comment: so basically if the page gets to a small size the text wraps to an extra line. I want the height of all the box's to adjust to the box with the greatest height. Check out the second fiddle am I closer?

Comment: @Drew If you trying to adjust the text in Box without overflow so comment jquery and check it will automatically adjust in box.

Comment: @Drew check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pfrv0qgx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're JS code to work in resize must be:

```
function checkWidth() {
    var text = $('.text').height();
    $(".text").height(text+10);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth();
    $(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
});
```

But you have an Logic error: `$(node).height($(node).height())` - do nothing!

Comment: Thanks this almost works how i want it to, so basically if the page gets to a small size the text wraps to an extra line.  I want the height of all the box's to adjust to the box with the greatest height.  Check out this fiddle am I closer?  http://jsfiddle.net/d1a0rv8r/

Comment: Don't use `each` in this task, because of this code works async and you set .text sizes before this code complete. Use simple `var nodeList = $('.text'); for (var i=0; i<nodeList.length; i++) {nodeList[i];}`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using a for loop sorry I am pretty new to JavaScript could you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: You sir are a true gentleman, thank you.  Just curious do you have any idea how doing this will effect performance compared to using something like https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height?

Answer (score 1):

I think the syntax you are looking for is:

```
$(window).resize( function() { checkWidth() });
```